# Firebase Cloud Message not showing up in Angular page

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try set my web app to receive cloud message, using the last sdk of firebase (9.21.0).
in app.module.ts I have configured access to firebase and messaging like this.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getMessaging } from 'firebase/messaging/sw';
```

initializing app I get messaging

```
const app = initializeApp(environment.fireApp);
const msg = getMessaging(app);.
```

in app.component.ts for get messaagei using different metods, but in chrome devtools I see received message, but not in the page or console., what i´m doing wrong.
this is code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    Notification.requestPermission().then((permis) => {
      if (permis === 'granted') {
        console.log('Permision Granted');
        getToken(this.msg, { vapidKey: <vapidKey> }).then((currentToken) => {
          if (currentToken) {
            console.log(currentToken);
          } else {
            console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
          }
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Unable to get permision');
      }
    })
    this.pushsw.messages.subscribe((msh) => {
      console.log('Push msg', msh);
    })
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then((reg) => {
      console.log('This is msg', reg);
      reg?.showNotification('Hello World', { body: 'This is body of notification' })
      reg?.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
        console.log(event);
      })
    })
    onMessage(this.msg, (payload) => {
      console.log('Message received. ', payload);
    });
    self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
      console.log('Self Event', event);
    })
  }
```

its look like onMessage not working

Comment: in OnMessage, you need to map the payload to a property on the component and ensure it is assigned properly in the .html template.

Comment: In this moment only i want to see msg in console.log(), the rest i know.

Comment: II noticed you didn't import onMessage -  import { getMessaging, onMessage } from "firebase/messaging";

Comment: Thanks all for coments, finaly i find solution, here is what is needed, https://angularprojekt.blogspot.com/2021/11/firebase-cloud-messaging-en-angular-13.html